# Square is falling down faster on each confirmed game over alert

Tags: javascript, html

I have square in canvas which goes up when user clicks the canvas.Otherwise falls down.When square hits the ground,Game Over alert appears and expects action from user.If confirmed by user ,game starts again but problem here is ,starts to fall always faster when user wants to play again.Here my JS code below.How can I make its falling down speed constant as same as first always?

```
var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var recWidth,recHeight,xPos,yPos;
var gameStarted=false;

boxInitializer();

function startGame(){
     this.gameStarted=true;
     init();
}

function boxInitializer(){
    this.recWidth = 100;
    this.recHeight = 100;
    this.xPos = (document.getElementById("gameCanvas").width/2) - (recWidth/2);
    this.yPos = (document.getElementById("gameCanvas").height/2) - (recHeight/2);
    ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,recWidth,recHeight);
    console.log('XPos:'+xPos+'YPos:'+yPos);
}

function init(){
    if(gameStarted){
        const myVar=250;
        this.c.addEventListener('click', Up,false);
        setInterval(Down,myVar);
        console.log(myVar);
        setInterval(obstacleGenerator,2000); 
        function obstacleGenerator(){

            console.log("Obstacle generated");
        }
        function drawSquare(){
            this.ctx.fillRect(this.xPos,this.yPos,this.recWidth,this.recHeight);
        }
        function clearSquare(){
            this.ctx.clearRect(this.xPos,this.yPos,this.recWidth,this.recHeight);
        }
        function Up()
        {
           clearSquare();
            yPos-=40;
            drawSquare();
        } 
        function Down()
        {
            clearSquare();
            this.yPos+=30;
            console.log(yPos);
            drawSquare();
            if(this.yPos>=830){
                this.gameStarted=false;
                GameOver();
            }
        }
        function GameOver(){
            if (confirm("GAME OVER!")) {
            clearSquare();
            boxInitializer();
            startGame();
            } else {

            }
        }    

    }

}
```

**JS Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/qmz3186h/

Comment: your example link doesn't work.  It's showing text in the output.

Comment: @jusopi try again

Comment: My guess is that the function that controls the falling speed is called 2 times, then three times.Maybe you should remember to stop the timed interval using `clearInterval` at some point?

Comment: @Techek clearInterval() in GameOver() you mean?I removed it and didn't work.Also other clearInterval() in Up() method isnt being called when canvas not clicked so only in Down() method its being called just once I mean.

Comment: your `init()` function is recursive, every time a player decides to play again it starts another instance of it, while the previous one still exists. This seems to be why your falling speed increases with each iteration

Comment: @KaranShishoo Well spotted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to clear your `gameStarted` Down interval on `gameOver`

you can have a variable to hold interval, and clear same in Game over function

```
var interval; // initialize at top

interval = setInterval(Down,myVar); // replace with this in `if(gameStarted)` loop

clearInterval(interval ) // clear interval on confirm("GAME OVER!")
```

Comment: Oh!Such a stupid mistake.Thanks for your answer .Yeah  I forgot to clear that interval